# Fluent Nhibernate Composite Key Not Generating Joins For Referenced Entities

Tags: nhibernate, fluent, queryover, composite-key

I have a mapping with a composite key as below:

```
CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.CreatedBy, "member_key")
            .KeyReference(x => x.Box, "box_key");
```

This works fine for simple gets and inserts, however it is not generating joins with the tables mentioned in the reference where I try and use them as part of a query.

So this:

```
return _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().QueryOver<BoxMember>()
            .Where(x => x.Box.Id == boxId)
            .Where(x => x.Member.DeletedDate == null)
            .Fetch(x => x.Box).Eager
            .Fetch(x => x.CreatedBy).Eager
            .List();
```

Generates the following SQL:

```
    SELECT this_.member_key     as member1_5_0_,
       this_.box_key        as box2_5_0_
FROM   box_member this_
WHERE  this_.box_key = '2750e160-ba72-4a70-b554-9fd600e3cfd0' /* @p0 */
and    m1_.deleted_date is null;
```

Comment: does it join when you leave out the filter for it? `.Where(x => x.Box.Id == boxId)`

Comment: did you manage to fix it somehow ?

Comment: You need to mark the answer below as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. Adding Reference mapping  helped, but the issue makes no sense anyway:

Try this:

```
CompositeId() 
            .KeyReference(x => x.CreatedBy, "member_key") 
            .KeyReference(x => x.Box, "box_key"); 
Reference(x => x.CreatedBy);
Reference(x => x.Box);
```

Comment: Uh freaking this. This solved my problem. Why the hell doesn't keyreference automatically do this?